# Display same row but different column value on a single page

Tags: crystal-reports

My report currently looks like:

```
id name semester loanAmt
2  Ajay  1       2500
2  Ajay  2       3000
3  raj   1       1000
```

Instead, I want these records to appear on page 1:

```
id name semester loanAmt
2  Ajay  1       2500
         2       3000
```

...and these on page 2:

```
id name semester loanAmt
3  raj   1       1000
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So just to be clear, you want each set of values for a particular "Name" or "ID" to get their own page?

If you want that to happen every time, Group your data by "Name" or "ID" (whichever you prefer) and in the Section Expert if it isn't already. Then select the Paging tab and check "New Page After". You may also want to check "Keep Together" for completeness.

Additionally, you can format your ID and Name fields to suppress if `"ID" = PREVIOUS("ID")` and `"Name" = PREVIOUS("Name")` respectively. This will suppress duplicate names as seen here:

```
id name semester loanAmt
2  Ajay  1       2500
         2       3000
```

Comment: I think you'd need to suppress ID in the same way you suppress name.

Comment: Good catch, adding that in.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of using "Underlay Following Section" on a Group Header, but realize that wouldn't work well when you need to suppress multiple columns like the OP does.

Comment: @sujiths Glad to hear it! Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it was indeed the one you needed. Cheers!